# How to wrap android code in activity(dot)xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to wrap my long android code in activity(dot)xml, so i don't need to use horizontal scroll for editing my code

I'am using android studio, i had tried those codes

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum "/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
    ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum "/>
```

In the first code, i got preview "lorem ipsum" in one sentence, but the code very long, didn't wrap, i must use horizontal scroll to editing.

In the second code, if I press enter in the middle code (force to wrap), i got preview "lorem ipsum" in two sentences.

What i want is, the android code can be wrap like the second code and the preview "lorem ipsum" still in one sentence like the first code.

Please help me, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a preference option called "soft wrapping":

[image]

Comment: i had use that setting, in java file, my code can auto wrap. But in layout xml file, my code can't auto wrap

Comment: thank you for helping, but my problem has not been solved